# Animate background-color using jquery and HTML5 data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to animate the `background-color` of a specific div using a combination of jQuery and the HTML5 `data` attribute. I'm open to the best way of achieving this however I believe the above would make most sense for my situation.

I am wanting to fade between an array of colours set using the Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields plugin, hence the reasoning for using the `data` attribute, so I can set these colours dynamically in the DOM.

Below is the markup for the `div`, including the colours, however what I have no idea how to achieve is the jQuery to animate between all of the colours, ideally at random.

Can anybody assist? Thanks.

```
<div id="content" data-colors="<?php if( have_rows('dot_colours', 'option') ): ?><?php while( have_rows('dot_colours', 'option') ): the_row(); ?><?php the_sub_field('colour'); ?>,<?php endwhile; ?><?php endif; ?>
    ">
Content here.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

**HTML** (assuming PHP returns an array for the value of `data-colors`)

```
<div id="myDiv" data-colors='["#b3e45f", "red", "yellow", "green", "blue"]'></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const el = $('#myDiv');
const colors = el.data('colors');
let i = 0;

el.css("background-color", colors[i]);

function changeColor() {
  i++;
  i = i % colors.length;
  el.animate({backgroundColor: colors[i]},1000);
  setTimeout(changeColor,2500);
}

changeColor();
```

Here's a Codepen to demonstrate: https://codepen.io/MarkRabey/pen/MobeLo

**EDIT**: forgot to mention, color animations are available as part of jQuery UI, not jQuery. Without jQuery UI you could use CSS transition instead.

Add to your CSS:

```
#myDiv {
  transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

Change the `changeColor()` function to:

```
function changeColor() {
  i++;
  i = i % colors.length;
  el.css('background-color', colors[i]);
  setTimeout(changeColor,2500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here, this answer is via css transition .. you can also clear fadeing in with:

```
clearInterval( window.it );
```

```js
var arr = $('.ch').first().attr('data-colors'); // "red, green, blue, purple, gray"
arr = arr.split(','); // ["red", " green", " blue", " purple", " gray"]

// set attrib for first time
$('.ch').first().attr('len', 0 );

function changeColor(){
  var len = arr.length;
  var atm = $('.ch').first().attr('len');
  $('.ch').first().css( 'background-color', arr[ atm ] );
  if( atm == len ) $('.ch').first().attr('len', 0 );
  if( atm != len ) $('.ch').first().attr('len', parseInt(atm) + 1 );
}

window.it = setInterval( changeColor, 2000 );
```

```css
.ch{
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition:background 2s;
  -moz-transition:background 2s;
  -o-transition:background 2s;
  transition:background 2s;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
body{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ch" data-colors="red, green, blue, purple, gray">&nbsp;</div>
```